# Czech unicode issue in Python Django

Tags: python, unicode, cloudflare

I have this URL [https://českébudějovice.mysite.com/](https://%C4%8Desk%C3%A9bud%C4%9Bjovice.mysite.com/) and it's a Czech city name. When someone accesses that url, I extract the subdomain and query for City model object. So I have City model in Django and can successfully query that city thru shell:

```
>> City.objects.get(name='českébudějovice')
>> <City: České Budějovice, Czech Republic>
```

However today I received an exception on Sentry on production saying that 'City matching query does not exist' and the URL is shown like this:

```
xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g.mysite.com
```

Obviously, I don't have a City with the name 'xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g' hence I'm getting 'City matching query does not exist' error.

I've been trying to convert that weird subdomain to the actual name but no luck. I've tried below:

```
>> s='xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g'
>> print s.encode('utf8')
>> xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g
```

I'm using Cloudflare and I wonder if it's somehow converting url to that form instead of serving it as unicode to my server.

Comment: The encoding in domain names is not utf8. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) and it's a valid way of representing international domain names.

You can decode the string using the 'idna' codec:

```
>>> s = 'xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g'
>>> print(s.decode('idna'))
českébudějovice
```

If you're on Python 3, use [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) to decode punycode.

Comment: spasibo bratan :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
$ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Aug 13 2016, 16:41:35) 

>>> 'xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g'.decode('idna')
u'\u010desk\xe9bud\u011bjovice'

>>> print 'xn--eskbudjovice-deb41c5g'.decode('idna')
českébudějovice
```